# How to change LocalDate format resulting into a LocalDate without resulting into a String

Tags: java, formatting, localdate

In a need to convert Java `LocalDate` of the format of `dd-MM-yyyy` into a `LocalDate` of `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Trying with :

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate date = // LocalDate value in dd-MM-yyyy format
String stringDate = dateFormat.format(date);
LocalDate convertedDate = LocalDate.parse(stringDate, dateFormat);
```

But still it resulting into return a date in `dd-MM-yyyy` format. Any efficient way to do this?

Comment: You got something fundamental wrong. `LocalDate` doesn't have a format. It's just a date object. When you print a `LocalDate` object, its `toString()` method is called, and it uses `yyyy-MM-dd` format by default (maybe that varies with locales).

Comment: i see. yeah that makes sense. so is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: No, @dineshalwis, there isn’t. It’s also better to keep the date in a `LocalDate` and your desired format in a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

The default toString implementation in LocalDate.java seems to be hardwired with '-' as a separator. So all default print statements will result into same format. Seems only way out would be to use a formatter and get a string output.

```
return buf.append(monthValue < 10 ? "-0" : "-")
            .append(monthValue)
            .append(dayValue < 10 ? "-0" : "-")
            .append(dayValue)
            .toString();
```

Also, purpose of LocalDate.parse(..) is not to convert the date format. It's actually meant to just get a date value in String and give a resulting LocalDate instance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry i cant find a complete answer here. But thanks.